# WatchKit "unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value" when accessing IBOutlet in Glance on actual device

Tags: ios, swift, watchkit

I have a Glance and some `WKInterfaceLabel`s. I use `setHidden()` on them in `override func willActivate()` depending on some conditions.

```
class GlanceController: WKInterfaceController {
  @IBOutlet weak var lName: WKInterfaceLabel!
  ...

override func willActivate() {
    // This method is called when watch view controller is about to be visible to user
    super.willActivate()
    if(conditions) {
        lName.setHidden(false)
    } else {
        lName.setHidden(true)
    }
  }
}
```

This works in simulator but on actual watch, I get `fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value` at `lName.setHidden()`.

Anyone saw this before?

Comment: Please post the actual error from the logs, and the code snippet it pertains to

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that you are not allowed to use `.setHidden()` in `Glance`, at least for the current version of `WatchKit`.

I redesign my UI completely to use a single label and it works. Obviously it does not look as nice as I intend.

I understand the restriction but really hope there is more documentation to save the trouble. Just like I only found out I can't scroll in `Glance` after spending time designing the UI.

Answer (score 0):

As your "lName" is declared as explicitly unwrapped optional, it safer to access the variable following way -

```
   if let validLName = lName {
     if(conditions) {
        validLName.setHidden(false)
     } else {
        validLName.setHidden(true)
     }
   }
}
```

Comment: It is true that your change will prevent the error but the code won't be executed completely. I think I found the answer (see my other reply)